# PDFPrinter driver with ability for custom file name

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation

Does anyone know of a PDF printer driver that allows you to programatically set the file name for printing/saving.
Im not sure if its possible with PDFCreator, but Im unable to figure it out.

So I am creating HTML Reports and have a print button to print it to PDF.

But now I have to automate it more so that it will be able to generate the PDF with a certain name. This without human interaction.

Answer (score 0):

[Win2PDF](https://www.win2pdf.com/pdf-automation.html) has several ways to do this.

- The [Auto-name](https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/automatically-name-pdf.html) feature can automatically name the PDF file, and can use the document title to name the files along with configurable date/time stamps. This can be configured with no changes to your program.
- The file name can also be set by your program using the Windows API or by setting a string value in the registry named [PDFDefaultFileName](https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/specifyinganoutputfilename.html).